# Load time is very slow in API while fetching data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using a simple query to list all the users in Laravel.

This is the query that I am using in Eloquent:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

I get all the required data, but the time to get is more than 1.3 Second. While using the same in Doctrine loads the data in 300 ms.

Is there any issue of Eloquent in Laravel???

Comment: will you please share how you check the time of sql query. I am also new in Laravel.

Comment: @webtuts4u install https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork and you can see how long it takes to execute your DB queries.

Comment: @webtuts4u I am using Postman to see the response time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [Your project dir]->laravel->app->config.php and change

`'url' => '127.0.0.1'`  instead of localhost and see if that makes any difference.

If that doesn't work you can install [Clockwork for laravel](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) which will provide you with a timeline of whats taking so long.

Here's an example of the timeline I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: That URL is just for running Laravel from the console. So no that won't change anything.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and tried many ways but nothing worked. Your fix solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This may help someone who is facing this kind of problems. I've had similar issues with a lumen api backend. My lumen api took about 30-35 seconds to return ~1500 data and it took about 1.2 seconds using raw php on a shared hosting.

I searched for hours to find the issue, but found nothing. stirredo's answer gave me the idea to measure the time for executing my queries. The execution time showed that there was nothing wrong with the eloquent methods, rather the issue was inside the return statement. The tutorial I followed for creating the api used something like this-

```
return response()->json([$data]);
```

I replaced this with-

```
return json_encode($data);
```

And this simple change improved my response time from ~30 seconds to ~2.5 seconds. May be the json() method just iterates the data over and over for generating the json, which in turn creates a huge delay in response. So this might be helpful if any newbies like me are trying to solve delayed response issues with laravel/lumen. Reference for [json()](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#other-response-types) and [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: This fixed my long responses. Thanks!

Comment: I have had the same issue in laravel 9 and by just doing return $data; sped the response up 100x. But why? isn't "return response()->json($data);" Laravel's preferred way? This is the only thread I can find on this issue. Does that mean that only a select few of us encounter this? We lose out on the added benefits of using response()->json(), but I'd rather that then my responses taking so much time. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: I've never found an answer to that question either. But observing the php source code and laravel source code showed that laravel wraps up json using their JsonResponse class, which adds additional validation and conditional branches. Which shows why it needs more time to process the data. On the other hand the raw json encode/decode method is written in c (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json.c), which by definition should run significantly faster as no additional compilation is needed. So I guess we either get faster responses or additional features, but not both.

Comment: @AbirPartha I had the strangest discovery today. I remove a composer package and my response()->json() times went back down to match the same speeds as json_encode(). The package is "ryangjchandler/blade-tabler-icons". It seems so unrelated that it makes no sense, but I have tested a dozen times now, adding and then removing that package and the results are consistent.

Comment: Well that package might've been causing the issue in laravel, but I faced this issue on a project which was completed using lumen. It had no blade files as it was used for purely backend api purpose. I'm currently migrating the project to laravel octane, I'll look into the package and see if removing it makes any difference. Thanks for the heads up.